# Avoiding unecessary recompilation with makefile

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

I'm using makefile with gcc. Every c file has an accompanying header:

main.c main.h
test.c test.h

main.c includes main.h and test.h

test.c includes test.h

I want to avoid recompiling every c file. Makefile is ran without -B argument.

I can write the whole makefile manually and specify every dependency. When editing headers only the necessary c files get recompiled. An edit in test.h will recompile both c files and a change in main.h will only recompile main.c. As it should.

This doesn't work when I switch to the more automated approach:

```
OBJ = main.o test.o

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o main $(OBJ)
```

A change in test.h will only recompile test.c. Leaving main.c in the old with the old version of test.h header. I'm forced to run makefile with -B, if I want to use this approach.

I can specify the headers manually:

```
DEPS = main.h sort.h

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Then a change in main.h recompiles both main.c and test.c, the latter being unnecessary.

Updating every change in the makefile is unwieldy if I have a lot of files, and using the automated approach will increase compilation times.

Is there a better solution, one that only recompiles the needed files, or is specifying everything manually the only way?

Comment: look up gcc options to output Makefile dependencies based on include files.

Comment: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: @chqrlie Sorry, that is a dead end for me, I'm a newbie with make&gcc, thus asking here for a constructive answer.

Comment: If you're not able to follow the examples to get automatic dependency tracking, then the answer to your question in the final paragraph is "there is no better solution (that you are able to implement), so specifying manually is the only way".

Comment: @MadScientist No, I'm not able to follow a long external link, because I don't know what automated dependency tracking is specifically. That is why I'm asking here. I though this is a Q&A site.

Comment: You use the term "dependency" in your question so one assumes you know what dependencies are.  The first two paragraphs on that page explain: _One of the most important, and yet potentially frustrating, tasks that is required to allow any make-based build environment to function properly is the correct listing of dependencies in the makefile.
This document describes a very useful method for having make itself create and maintain these dependencies completely automatically._ What about this is not clear?

Comment: This site is for answering questions, and very often the answer is "this question has been asked and answered many times before... look here for more information".

Comment: Your default rule `%.o: %.c %.h` is fine, for you need to add extra dependencies to tell make what they are.  In your example you need an extra line `main.o: test.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify additional dependencies of `main.o` using another line:

```
OBJ = main.o test.o

main.o: test.h
```

Comment: I get an error: *No rule to make target 'test.h', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop*

Comment: I understood from your post that you have files `main.h`, `main.c`, `test.h`, and `test.c`. Is that not true?

Comment: Nevermind I had a typo :-(. Thank you this solves my problem.

Comment: Note if you ever create a `.c` file that doesn't have an associated header file using the same prefix (e.g., `foo.c` but no `foo.h`), this makefile will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to specify manually, though, you're doing it wrong; you don't want to add the dependencies to the pattern where it takes effect for *every* object file.  You define it separately for each object file so they're only rebuilt when the right ones change:

```
OBJ = main.o test.o

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

main: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o main $(OBJ)

main.o: main.h test.h
test.o: test.h
```

Maintaining those last lines is what the automated dependency generation does, if you decide you want to try to use it.

Comment: This is a little more verbose but much easier to maintain by hand.  That's what most people do and it is quite sufficient for most projects. Once you master make and the C compiler, you can reach Jedi level where the lines can be computed automatically.  It took me more than 10 years to finally decide it was worth the effort to automate this.

Comment: Another dependency often overlooked is `%.o: %.c Makefile` etc.  Whenever you change the Makefile, it is wise to recompile everything, just in case some compile options or command line defines have changed.